# Batch-file programing to get specified line into variable by checking other key word

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to write batch file code to check whether given line is present in text file or not. If it is present I want to get specific line(depending on line number) after that line into  variable..
Can anyone help me?

For example
I have text file as...
EX1
EX2
Ex3
EX4
Ex5

now I want to search weather Ex3 is present in batch file or not.
If it is present I want Ex5(2nd line after that) into variable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on my box:

```
@echo off
SET searchterm=Ex3
SET /a lineafter=2
SET filename=lst.txt
:: --------------
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /a c=0
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN (%filename%) DO (
  if !c! GTR 0 (
    IF %lineafter% EQU !c! (
      SET result=%%i
      GOTO :linefound
    )
    SET /a c=!c! + 1
  ) ELSE (
    IF "%%i"=="%searchterm%" (
      SET /a c=1
    )
  )
)
echo No result
GOTO :EOF
:linefound
echo Result: %result%
```

Just enter your values in the lines 2-4.